# Do I need to manually restart my app on EC2 if the server restarts?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This is my first time with EC2 so keep that in mind. I spun an EC2 instance and put a really basic nodejs/express app up on it. I connected to the ec2 server via the terminal on my personal computer and ran node app.js to start the app and everything is running fine. The part I am confused about is how long this will run for. Ideally, I just want it to sit there and not touch it and have it run for hopefully years. Will it do this? If not what do I need to do? What if the server restarts for some reason? What is the common practice here?

Answer (score 5):

Go to root directory of your project and type this command to run the server permanently.

```
sudo npm install forever -g
forever start -c "node app.js" ./
```

Comment: I tried this and it said "forever: command not found" Is this a package I install?

Comment: Yes, you have to install forever package on the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog](https://mrvautin.com/running-nodejs-applications-in-production-forever-vs-supervisord-vs-pm2/) may be helpful, in setting up node for production environments